# Unimplemented SQL generation for predicate

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I have a DB with the following one-to-many relation:
Device -properties-> Property

I want to get a device that has atleast one property with a certain displaytype.

```
    NSArray *energyDisplayTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:18],[NSNumber numberWithInt:39],[NSNumber numberWithInt:50],[NSNumber numberWithInt:62],[NSNumber numberWithInt:63], nil];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSError *error;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"properties.displayType IN %@", energyDisplayTypes];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *products= [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

I keep getting this exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : properties.displayType IN {18, 39, 50, 62, 63}'
```

I don't have that much experience with databases so it's propably something simple. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `properties` is a to-many relationship, then you need to indicate *which* property's display type you want to match against your array.  There are three options: any, all, or none.  I suspect you want *any* of the properties' display types to match, so you would use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY properties.displayType IN %@", energyDisplayTypes];
```

Comment: I thought I tried that...well it worked anyway! Thanks!